# DragonFire SDK NetSend Response

Tags: c++

I recently pruchased DragonFire SDK and I'm having a slight problem. I am using a NetSend function to send details to my PHP Script on my server and it is returning the correct information, but with a slight 'twist' to it. This is my PHP Script:

```
<?php
$email = isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : "";
$password = isset($_GET['password']) ? $_GET['password'] : "";
if ($email == "tom") {
    echo 1;
} else {
    echo 0;
}
?>
```

And this is the C++ I'm using:

```
int login_response(int event, char *response, int length) {
    printf(response);
    return event;
}
```

The response is:

```
0ýýýý««««««««
```

Unless I enter 'tom' as the email, then it's:

```
1ýýýý««««««««
```

I'm not sure why it is doing this at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the previous answer, C and C++ assume that strings are terminated with a null (\0), so functions like printf() will expect that; but DragonFireSDK's NetSend doesn't always use this convention, and it assumes you're going to look at the value in the length variable. The above code simply forces the null to be in place for printf()'s benefit.

That may not be the safest solution. You don't know that the block of memory that NetSend is sending to the callback is something you can safely write to, even if you then restore the original value when you're done, as is done above. The most bulletproof approach would be to copy the string to somewhere else like a local variable only to the length specified, if you have to use printf(); or, better yet, just use the data where it is but only read it, if you don't need to go to printf().  For instance, here's a clumsy but safe version:

```
char *cp;
for (cp = response; cp-response < length; cp++) {
  printf("%c",*cp);
}
printf("\n");
```

However, this is probably being paranoid. I doubt this or any other version of DragonFireSDK is likely to use a buffer you can't safely write to.

Answer (score 1):

```
int OnResponse(int event, char *response, int length)
{  
    int resvalue = response[length];
    response[length] = 0;
    printf(response);
    response[length] = resvalue;

    return event;
}
```